# ASP MVC checkout with PayPal for total sum only

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, paypal, e-commerce

I have a web store in ASP.NET MVC for which I created the entire workflow - adding to cart, proceeding to checkout and writing the order to DB. Now, I need to implement PayPal payment.

I was wondering if there is a way to make the purchase without creating the entire cart on PayPal all over again, but allow payment for the total value of the entire cart (which I already have as an information) with complete disregard for the cart items.

For example, I have a guitar and a guitar pick. Customer orders a guitar and 5 picks. Can I implement PayPal in a way that I can send `guitarPrice * guitarQty + pickPrice * pickQty` with complete abstraction of cart and its items?

Comment: Check this out - https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/ I don't know anything about ASP.NET but if you are capable of integrating this button it will do exactly what you're looking for! All you do is pass the total and that's it!

Comment: @GageHendyYaBoy Thanks! Put it in an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [this](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/) button is what you need.
I'm not familiar with ASP.NET but this button has all of the functionality you're looking for.

Comment: Yes, integration is performed in JavaScript, so it's very flexible :)